# Generic method to return same object Type as input

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create a method, that accepts any type of object, and returns an instantiated version of that object, something like:

```
public static T GetObjectFromJToken<T>(JToken jToken, string jTokenTag) where T : new ()
{
    if (jToken[tag] != null && jToken[tag].ToString() != "")
    {
        return new T(JToken.Parse(jToken[tag].ToString()));
    }
    return new T();
}
```

And then be able to use this method as something like:

```
MyObject myObject = GetObjectFromJToken<MyObject>(jToken, "someJsonTag");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Note that the `new()` constraint only guarantees the type has a parameterless constructor.  You'd need to use reflection in order to populate property values, but you're better off using existing methods from a Json library that should do that for you.

Comment: Which kind of object is represented by `T`? Do you need to pass a string and than parse it to specific value?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to get any type of object coming from a JToken, this can be any user created object, so I would like to tell the method what kind of object should be used to parse the Jtoken, and then return the constructed object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JToken.ToObject` generic method like so:

```
public static T GetObjectFromJToken<T>(JToken jToken, string jTokenTag) where T : class, new()
{
    return jToken[jTokenTag]?.ToObject<T>() ?? new T();
}
```

Comment: This returns null if the key isn't found; that's not what he wants.